# Инициализация std::unique_ptr в дружественном классе

Tags: c++

Привет.

Вроде бы проблема проста, но я с ней никогда не сталкивался и простым поиском с ходу не нашёл, поэтому решил не терять сил и времени и задать вопрос.

Пример:

```
#include <memory>

struct A {
protected:
    A() {}
    friend class B;
};

struct B {
    std::unique_ptr <A> a;
    B() : a( std::make_unique<A>() ) {}
};

int main() {
    B b;
}
```

Этот пример не скомпилируется. Но если убрать **protected** или заменить **std::unique_ptr** на обычный указатель, то всё будет нормально.

Я же не хочу избавляться ни от того, ни от другого.
Как быть?

Comment: Доступ к коструктору А у класса Б есть, только он им не пользуется. Воспользоваться им пытается функция `std::make_unique`, у которой этого доступа нет. Отсюда и проблемы.

Comment: Попробуйте зафрендить ее, или что там у нее внутри. Тот, кто вызывает конструктор А, должен иметь доступ, т.е. быть или наследником, или другом.

Comment: @Arkady, я это понимаю. Класс B является другом класса A.

Comment: Да хоть внучатым племянником %) При чем тут класс Б, если это пытается делать функция std::make_unique?
`Класс А` купил в банке ячейку и сказал, что доступ к ней имеет только он, и еще его друг `класс Б`. `Класс Б` послал в банк своего приятеля `std::make_unique`, которому, естественно, в банке оказали в доступе к ячейке. Потому что про него `класс А` ничего не говорил. Что тут не понятно? :)

Comment: @Arkady, мне почти всё понятно. Если тебе понятно абсолютно всё, тогда дай ответ.

Comment: Его дал Влад. Вот доказательство, с С++14. https://ideone.com/QvuZ8a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще можно так. Собственно, о чем и был мой второй комментарий два часа назад.

```
#include <memory>

struct A 
{
protected:
    A() {}
    friend struct B;
    friend std::unique_ptr<A> std::make_unique<A>();
};

struct B 
{
    std::unique_ptr <A> a;
    B() : a( std::make_unique<A>() ) {}
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

Прув: https://ideone.com/uesddg

УПД: с этим вариантом мы по прежнему создаем экземпляр при помощи make_unique, но при этом не даем "не друзьям" доступ до создания экземпляра.

```
#include <memory>

struct A 
{
protected:
    A() {}
    friend struct B;

    static std::unique_ptr<A> Create() { return std::make_unique<A>(); }
};

struct B 
{
    std::unique_ptr <A> a;
    B() : a( A::Create() ) {}
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

Comment: В этом не больше смысла, чем объявить просто конструктор класса A открытым, так как теперь все, как говорится, кому не лень, смогут создавать объекты класса A..

Comment: Это на случай, если автору принципиально использование именно make_unique(...). Он же написал "не хочу избавляться ни от того, ни от другого". А так Вами раписанное решение оптимально, имхо.

Comment: У меня не получается править. Но присмотритесь к словам Влада про то, что френдить unique_ptr не имеет большого смысла с точки зрения архитектуры. Возможно, Вам подойдет то, что написано после УПД. Или вариант Влада. Они более корректные.

Answer (score 3):

Функция `std::make_unique` не является дружественной функцией для класса `A`. Поэтому она не может создавать объекты класса `A`

Но вы можете написать

```
B() : a( new A() ) {}
```

Вот простая демонстрационная программа

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    struct A 
    {
    protected:
        A() {}
        friend struct B;
    };

    struct B 
    {
        std::unique_ptr <A> a;
        B() : a( new A() ) {}
    };

    B b;
}
```

Comment: @АнтонСазонов  Это корректный код, который современными компиляторами должен компилироваться. По крайней мере и MS VC++ 2015 и GCC его компилируют.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов У меня нет MinGW, но GCC 5.2.0 успешно компилирует кож с флагом C++ 14

Comment: @АнтонСазонов Совершенно ничего не понял. Что значит в main scope? Поместите определения структур, например, в глобальное пространство имен. Ы чем проблема-то:

Comment: @АнтонСазонов Ник после @ не выводится потому, что автор вопроса/ответа всегда получает уведомления о комментариях к этому вопросу/ответу.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов Мой ответ правильный. Я не понял вашу ссылку на main scope.  Очевидно, что она бессмысленна, так как совершенно не важно, где объявлены классы, и где создаются объекты классов.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Влад, возникает интересный вопрос...
Почему вы предоставили пример не вне скопа main!?

Comment: @АнтонСазонов Просто копировал в уже готовую программу с другим кодом, и мне было без разницы, куда скопировать данный код.

Comment: Дураку понятно, что std::make_unique не является дружественной функцией.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов По-моему вы слишком самокритичны.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, возможно. Тем не менее, вместо того, чтобы дать ответ, вы стали придераться.

Comment: Ответ на вопрос, где?

Comment: @АнтонСазонов Я вам ответил на вопрос.